# PowerShell - Send Email Function

Tags: powershell

I created a function for PowerShell using the old skool method of sending email via PowerShell using Net.Mail.MailMessage. It works fine, however, I know there are other ways of doing this in a simpler format using Send-MailMessage. I pieced together a Send-MailMessage function but I am getting an error when running it. Thoughts on either fixing the error or modifying the code to make it a little simpler? Note that the password.txt file that the script is pointing to is an encrypted password text file created from PowerShell.

Working Function

```
function sendMail ($message)
{
    "Sending Email"

    #SMTP server name
    $smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"

    #Creating a Mail object
    $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

    $emailPassword = Get-Content "C:\scriptfolder\password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
    $emailCredential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@domain.com", $emailPassword)

    #Add Attachment
    $Attachments = "attached file"

    #Creating SMTP server object
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
    $smtp.Port = 587
    
    $smtp.EnableSSl = $true
    $smtp.Credentials = $emailCredential

    #Email structure
    $msg.From = "sender@domain.com"
    $msg.To.add("user1@domain.com")
    $msg.CC.Add("user2@domain.com")
    $msg.CC.Add("user3@domain.com")
    $msg.subject = "***TEST***"
    $msg.body = "***TEST****"
    $msg.Attachments.Add($Attachments)

    #Sending email
    $smtp.Send($msg)

    "Email Sent"

};

Sendmail
```

Send-MailMessage that doesnt work

```
workflow SendEmail {

$emailPassword = Get-Content "C:\password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$emailCredential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@domain.com", $emailPassword)

InlineScript {

Send-MailMessage -From 'Sender <sender@domain.com>' -To 'User1 <user1@domain.com>', 'User2 <user2@domain.com>' -Subject 'Sending the Attachment' -Body "Forgot to send the attachment. Sending now." Attachments "attached file" -DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess, OnFailure -SmtpServer 'smtp.office365.com' -Port '587' -Credential $using:emailCredential
    }

}

SendMail
```

Error from Send-MailMessage

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Credential'. userName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```

New error after code changes

```
Send-MailMessage : Error in processing. The server response was: 5.7.3 STARTTLS is required to send mail [SA0PR13CA0028.namprd13.prod.outlook.com]
At SendEmail:9 char:9
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```

Comment: Change `System.Net.NetworkCredential` to `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential`, and add following parameters to the `ConvertTo-SecureString` call: `-AsPlaintext -Force`

Comment: It would also be better to store the password as a `SecureString` in the first place. If you can rely on the default behavior of the DPAPI, it's easy: `Get-Credential | Export-CliXml C:\path\to\cred.xml`, then read it back in with `$emailCredential = Import-CliXml C:\path\to\cred.xml`. If you have to use a custom key creating the `PSCredential` object is a little more work but reading it back in is just as easy, provided the cert is installed on the host decrypting the embedded `SecureString`. Right now the use of `password.txt` implies a plaintext string stored in a file on the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks Mathias -- I made those changes but am now getting a new error.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest - I generated the password using the following
`(get-credential).password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | set-content "C:\password2.txt"`